# Ionic: The back button is not showing when I refresh the page in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working in a project with ionic and when testing the app in the browser I go to the child state of one view and later i refresh the page and the back button disappears. I print the "$ionicHistory" object and the "backView" property is null.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('app.parent', {
    url: '/parent',
    views: {
      'tab-parent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/parent/parent.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    views: {
      'tab-parent@app': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/parent/child.html'
      }
    }
  })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/parent');

});
```

How i can solved it?

Thank you.

Comment: if you refresh the page also the `$ionicHistory` its clear.

Comment: Very thanks @gianlucatursi, so I made a condition that check if the backView property is null. If this is true the app redirect to the main page.

Answer (score 1):

as @gianlucatursi says, refreshing the page means that the object holding the application browsing history is reinitialized. the back button is only displayed if there are entries in the history object